# How to create lightning effect using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a rain scene in my game. I want to show the lightning effect. How to do it in cocos2d?

i used partical sysytem to show the rain. how to do the lightning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this?

Comment: @David: yes of course. i have gone through various algorithms and post for lightning. i have created rain fall using partical system. i want simplest way so i asked question. the question is not at all about rain fall.

Comment: Next time you post a question, just say what you found! :) It helps us help you better and may give you a better understanding of the response having it all in front of you on one page! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://britneyleejohnson.com/?p=144 for rain

http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/ for Lightning